# Match everything delimited by another regex?

Tags: python, regex, sentence

I'm currently trying to make a regex that will find all the sentences in a block of text, and so far I've got this;

```
(?=(?<!mr)\.|(?<!mrs)\.|\?|!)+
```

Which will find everything that *delimits* a sentence. I want the regex to find everything that's contained between what this regex finds, but I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: What about a split on this regex?

Comment: A split? What do you mean? Edit: OH man, that makes so much sense. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know python syntax but I presume it exists a split operator.

Comment: @user2373676 give an example with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Moved from your closed newer question)*
In your case, the lookbehinds should come before the periods.
Condensing your expression, it is

*Update* - Between it you could just split discarding delimiters

```
 # (?:(?<!mr)(?<!mrs)\.|\?|!)+

 (?:
      (?<! mr )
      (?<! mrs )
      \.
   |  \?
   |  !
 )+
```

Or, split keeping delimiters

```
 # ((?:(?<!mr)(?<!mrs)\.|\?|!)+)

 (
      (?:
           (?<! mr )
           (?<! mrs )
           \.
        |  \?
        |  !
      )+
 )
```

Comment: That works, but it still puts periods, exclamation and question marks inside the final list.

Comment: I put both ways. Split to keep/discard delimeters.

Comment: Remember, don't use lookbehinds after you match a literal unless you include that literal in the lookbehind. Example: `\.(?<!mr\.)` is equal to `(?<!mr)\.`

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
import re

pattern = r'(?=(?<!mr)\.|(?<!mrs)\.|\?|!)+' # I'm assuming this does what you say it does :)
text_block = """long block of sentences"""

sentences = re.split(pattern, text_block)
```

`sentences` will be a list containing the resulting substrings.
`re.split` will split `text_block` up into different elements of the returned `list`. It splits at each point where `pattern` matches.

Read about re here:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

EDIT(data imported from your closed newer question):

If you are getting the symbols like ?, ! etc. captured into your returned list aswell, you should try removing the outer parens, like this:

```
re.split(r"\.(?<!mr)|\.(?<!mrs)|\?|!", somestring)
```

Ex:

```
sentences = [s for s in re.split(r"\.(?<!mr)|\.(?<!mrs)|\?|!", somestring) if s]
```