# Match sentences with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, sentence

I have been mulling over this problem for a long time, and I cannot get it to work the way I want it to.

Right now, I have this expression to try and separate a block of text into sentences;

```
re.split(r"(\.(?<!mr)|\.(?<!mrs)|\?|!)+", somestring)
```

But no matter what I do, it always returns the periods, exclamation marks and question marks as items in the list, as well as the individual sentences. It doesn't discriminate between a normal period and Mr./Mrs. either, and just cuts them off as though they were the ends of sentences as well. What is wrong with my expression?

Comment: Can you show some example input text, and what you would like the output to be?

Comment: @Cyber [he won't..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511010/match-everything-delimited-by-another-regex#comment41654486_26511010)

Comment: remove the outer parens: re.split(r"\.(?<!mr)|\.(?<!mrs)|\?|!", x) Then do: sentences = [s for s in re.split(r"\.(?<!mr)|\.(?<!mrs)|\?|!", somestring)
if s]